# How to hack YARPP plugin to find related posts for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

Does anybody knows how I can hack YARPP (Yet-Another-Related-Post-Plugin) to find related posts for custom post type?

I really can't find any better related post plugin than YARPP. But, unfortunately, it does not support custom post-type yet.

Cheers!

Comment: This seems to be [planned by developer for implementation](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/1142), but no time estimates.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed this as well, but I'm looking for a hack due to my urgent need.

Comment: You should probably try to contact the developer and if your need is urgent to discuss your needs with his needs.

Answer (score 2):

Be wary that the plugin makes extensive use of the options table for caching. This can bring large sites to a crawl.

Comment: To a 'crawl'?? That doesn't sound good. Do you know of any better alternative...?

Comment: The performance issue is similar to the one described here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6897 Re alternatives, there are several in the plugin directory, but to be honest I'd be hard pressed to recommend any: I only know them to the extent that they crash my customers' larger sites. :-(

Comment: I am trying the Contextual Related Posts plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contextual-related-posts/). I think it uses the database to match the titles and the contents of posts. Will this also 'bring large sites to a crawl'? How about using tags to get related posts? Is this a better solution in regards to loading times for large sites? Cheers!

Comment: Tags is a much better option, yes.

Comment: using match against SQL works too, but it restricts you to MyISAM. On a large site that's a no no -- InnoDB and NDB are less prone to corruption.

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look at the plugin you'll need to change references to post_type == 'post' is changed to the name of your custom post type. They seemed to be in two files magic.php and includes.php

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work... or am I missing something?